# Laravel 7 multi parameter route error: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Missing required parameters for Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

My small project was in Laravel 5.8 and i decided to upgrade it to Laravel 7 using copy paste controllers, models, routes &...

Every things is fine but for route has an Associated array, I given this error:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Missing required parameters for [Route: admin-user-login] [URI: admin/users/{user}/login]. (View: /home/hamidreza/projects-tmp/laravel7/resources/views/admin/ads-index.blade.php)
```

Route:

```
Route::get('users/{user}/login', 'AdminUserController@login')->name('admin-user-login');
```

Error section in blade template:

```
{{ route('admin-user-login', ['user_id' => $ad->user_id]) }}
```

But it works if i use Indexed array like this:

```
{{ route('admin-user-login', [$ad->user_id]) }}
```

Or this one:

```
{{ route('admin-user-login', $ad->user_id) }}
```

I need only Associated array, specialy for multi parameter routes.

Comment: Hi, your route wait for `user` parameter, but you put `user_id` for it. Why?

Comment: If it hepls you, let me know. I store it like a answer for your question.

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov Hi, Thank you for your attention, it helped! Did you know why i haven't error in laravel 5.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route in `web.php` wait for paramenter named `user`, but you put `user_id` paramenter for it and it throws exeption for you.

In your case in should be something like this:

`// config/web.php
Route::get('users/{user}/login', 'AdminUserController@login')->name('admin-user-login');`

After that, in your controller:

`route('admin-user-login', ['user' => $user]);`

or:

`$user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
route('admin-user-login', compact('user'));`

or in blade templates:
`{{ route('admin-user-login', ['user' => $user]) }}`

More info in Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: Thank you for your help.